# Change js file code

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I just ran a website through the wc3 validator and found some errors that I need to fix.
Now, I’m quite new to magento so slightly confused where to find certain bits of the code.
I need to find this code in the head and change the img tag in the `<noscript></noscipt>` :

```
  <!-- Facebook Ads Toolbox for Magento -->
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '144265390');
fbq('track', 'PageView', {source: 'magento'});
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=144265390&ev=PageView&noscript=1&cd[source]=magento"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

I know you probably can’t tell me where to find it, but maybe some suggestions on where I could possibly look?

Answer (score 0):

It could be in page/html/head.phtml in your template, or it could be inserted via the admin.

> System > Configuration > Design > Head

Comment: Tried both of them but no luck, thanks anyway!